# Why is the field "compute target" for data drift monitoring in Azure ML studio still blank whereas I have a compute instance?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a compute instance:

Virtual machine size
STANDARD_DS3_V2 (4 Cores, 14 GB RAM, 28 GB Disk)

Processing Unit
CPU - General purpose

But, I'm not able to access it when trying to set it for data drift monitoring.
The dropdown list is empty. I can't understand why. Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You must give a **cluster** compute instance to do data drift in Azure Machine Learning Studio. As it is not clear, I'm planning to add something in the documentation of Azure.